# Go to end of last pasted region

Tags: cursor-movement, jump

Sometimes `` `] `` works, but not after inserting some new text somewhere.

How can I jump to the end (and/or start) of the last region of text I pasted with some variant of `p`?

---

`` `] `` does not work here:

```
vim --clean
ione
two
three
four<ESC>ggVGyGpOhello<ESC>`]
```

The cursor stays on hello instead of jumping to the end of the pasted text.

Comment: If I understand the question right, it should work without any extra effort.

Comment: Yeah... Can you give an example where `\`[` doesn't work? Can you reproduce that under `vim --clean`?

Comment: @filbranden added to the question

Comment: It makes sense `\`]` doesn't work because it is literally "To the last character of the previously **changed** or yanked text", so as soon as inserting new text... that counts as a change, and that's why `\`]` no longer jumps to the end of the pasted text

Comment: @Mass what should work

Comment: You can always set a non-volatile mark, or use g; to go back through the change list

Comment: @D.BenKnoble `g;` doesn't work for me, it seems to go to the start of the region (it's also very slow...)

Comment: Slow? It navigates the change list; I’ve never had it respond slowly. It may not be efficient if there are many intervening changes, which is why I suggested using a non-volatile mark